# Connect a Time Capsule to the ADSL modem/router using powerline adaptors?

Tags: time-capsule, ethernet

I need to place my Time Capsule a fair distance from my ADSL router, and cannot easily run an Ethernet cable between the two.   Can I use a pair of Powerline ethernet adaptors to make the connection?  If so, any advice as to recommended make/model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. From a network point of view, [power line communication devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_line_communication) act like a bridge (or a switch, if they support more than 2 ends). That means they should act completely transparent (not accounting for transmission errors or other problems).

Comment: No specific recommendations, but you should mention which country you're in, as the models (and standards) vary greatly, due to different sockets and power standards.

Comment: I use the D-Link PowerLine AV Adapters. I'm in Canada and it's compatible with US as well. I get around 85Mbps over the power lines.